# Statically linking Haskell program using stack on Amazon Linux, to use on AWS Lambda

Tags: linux, haskell, amazon-ec2, haskell-stack

I'm trying to build a statically linked 'hello world' Haskell program on an EC2 instance, with a view to running it on AWS Lambda.

My only modification to the 'simple' stack.yaml is:

```
ghc-options:
    "*": -static -optc-static -optl-static -optl-pthread
```

I first got the following errors:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-0-238 lambdatest]$ stack build
lambdatest-0.1.0.0: configure
Configuring lambdatest-0.1.0.0...
lambdatest-0.1.0.0: build
Preprocessing executable 'lambdatest' for lambdatest-0.1.0.0...
Linking .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.4.0/build/lambdatest/lambdatest ...
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmp
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthread
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The first thing I tried was to install gmp-devel:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-0-238 lambdatest]$ sudo yum install gmp-devel.x86_64
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Package gmp-devel-6.0.0-11.16.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

but it looks like that isn't the issue.

Next I installed glibc-static and gmp-static, and now the error I see is:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-0-238 lambdatest]$ stack build
lambdatest-0.1.0.0: build
Preprocessing executable 'lambdatest' for lambdatest-0.1.0.0...
Linking .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.4.0/build/lambdatest/lambdatest ...
/home/ec2-user/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-7.10.2/lib/ghc-7.10.2/rts/libHSrts.a(Linker.o): In function `internal_dlopen':

Could not resolve file /home/ben/ghc-7.10.2/rts/Linker.c
```

But when I run the identical 'stack build' command a second time, it completes without error.

Comment: Perhaps stack has a verbose mode that will show what commands it's trying to run. Seeing what it passes to ld would probably help with your debugging efforts.

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1603) on the stack repository. This guy named `ben` is about to become famous for being part of a widely distributed GHC binary :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So what worked for me was:

Add the fpcomplete repo:

```
curl -sSL https://s3.amazonaws.com/download.fpcomplete.com/centos/7/fpco.repo | \
sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/fpco.repo
```

Install stack:

```
sudo yum -y install stack
```

Install ghc:

```
stack setup
```

Create a new stack project:

```
stack new lambdatest simple
```

Modify stack.yaml with the following flags:

```
ghc-options:
    "*": -static -optc-static -optl-static -optl-pthread
```

Install static versions of libraries:

```
sudo yum install glibc-static
sudo yum install gmp-static
```

Then run `stack build` *twice*!

The resulting executable runs OK on my EC2 instance and also runs on AWS Lambda when started by a Node.js launcher function.

Comment: Don't suppose you know how this could be done on Ubuntu? There's no `glibc-static` AFAIK!